# Strange Errors. Using rand() and arrays within a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, random, error-handling

I really can not explain what is going on with my program. I really can't spot what may be causing the problems. It occurs within this function

```
void test()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    questionNo = 1;

    for (testLoop = 0; testLoop < 10; ++testLoop)
    {
        const char opArray[3] = { 'x', '+', '-' };
        int pickValue = rand() % 3;
        char Operator = opArray[pickValue];

        int n1 = rand() % 20 + 1;
        int n2 = rand() % 20 + 1;

        if (Operator = '+')
            answer = n1 + n2;
        else if (Operator = '-')
            answer = n1 - n2;
        else
            answer = n1 * n2;

        cout << "Question " << questionNo << "\n";
        ++questionNo;
        cout << n1 + " " << Operator + " " << n2 << "?";
        userAnswer = cin.get();

        if (userAnswer = answer)
        {
            cout << "\n\n Correct!\n";
            system("cls");
            ++score;
        }
        else
        {
        cout << "\n\n Incorrect!\n";
        system("cls");
        }
        Sleep(500);
    }
    cout << "You scored " << score << " out of 10!";
    fileWrite(score);
}
```

An example of what occurs is the following.
This outputs to console

Question 1
@Øÿ×╝×³×0ƒ11?

What even is that???
It also skips two questions every time. For example it goes

"Question 1"
"Question 3"
"Question 5"

Comment: Adding a character to a c-string is (in most cases) is wrong: `Operator + " "`

Comment: You have: `cout << n1 + " " << Operator + " " << n2 << "?";` — but you should probably be using `<<` in place of `+` both times: `cout << n1 << " " << Operator << " " << n2 << "?";`  At the very least, that looks more orthodox.

Comment: `if (Operator = '+')` should be `if (Operator == '+')` (Notice the double `=`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` in this code snippet

```
    if (Operator = '+')
        answer = n1 + n2;
    else if (Operator = '-')
        answer = n1 - n2;
    else
        answer = n1 * n2;
```

Chnage it the following way

```
    if (Operator == '+')
        answer = n1 + n2;
    else if (Operator == '-')
        answer = n1 - n2;
    else
        answer = n1 * n2;
```

There is the same error in this statement

```
   if (userAnswer = answer)
```

Also instead of

```
   userAnswer = cin.get();
```

use `operator >>`.

```
sin >> userAnswer;
```

There is also a typo in this statement

```
    cout << n1 + " " << Operator + " " << n2 << "?";
```

There should be

```
    cout << n1 << " " << Operator << " " << n2 << "?";
```

Comment: Also near the end he has `if (userAnswer = answer)` which needs to be changed to `if (userAnswer == answer)`

Comment: I have changed this in my program and I don't have any of those weird characters anyone. However, it know just blurts out a single number without an operator.

It also still skips a question each time. Going from question 3 to 5 for example

Comment: @Reece See my uodated post.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
cout << n1 + " " << Operator + " " << n2 << "?";
```

You should be using `<<` in place of `+` both times:

```
cout << n1 << " " << Operator << " " << n2 << "?";
```

The `n1 + " "` term is adding the value of `n1` to the address where the one-blank string is stored, generating a `char *`, and then the `<<` is printing whatever garbage it finds beyond the end of that string (assuming `n1` is positive and greater than 1, or what it finds before the string if it is negative).  Effectively, you've written `&" "[n1]` for that term. Similarly with the other addition expression.

This explains the peculiar output you are getting.  You also have multiple problems with assignment `=` where you intend comparison `==`.